# Analyze weather data stored in csv

Tags: matlab

I have some weather data stored in a csv file in the form of: „id, date, temperature, rainfall“, with id being the weather station and, obviously, date being the date of measurement. The file contains the data of 3 different stations over a period of 10 years. 
What I'd like to do is analyze the data of each station and each year. For example: I'd like to calculate day-to-day differences in temperature [abs((n+1)-n)] for each station and each year.

I thought while-loops could be a possibility, with the loop calculating something as long as the id value is equal to the one in the next row.
But I’ve no idea how to do it.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to have actual data to work on and specifics as to what kind of output format is expected. Basically, ins and outs :) With the little info provided, I figured I would generate random data for you in the first section, and then calculate some stats in the second. I include the loop as an example since that's what you asked, but I highly recommend using vectorized calculations whenever available, such as the one done in summary stats.

```matlab
%% example for weather stations
% generation of random data to correspond to what your csv file looks like
rng(1); % keeps the random seed for testing purposes
nbDates = 1000; % number of days of data
nbStations = 3; % number of weather stations
measureDates = repmat((now()-(nbDates-1):now())',nbStations,1); % nbDates days of data ending today
stationIds = kron((1:nbStations)',ones(nbDates,1)); % assuming 3 weather stations with IDs [1,2,3]
temp = rand(nbStations*nbDates,1)*70+30; % temperatures are in F and vary between 30 and 100 degrees
rain = max(rand(nbStations*nbDates,1)*40-20,0); % rain fall is 0 approximately half the time, and between 0mm and 20mm the rest of the time
csv = table(measureDates, stationIds, temp, rain);
clear measureDates stationIds temps rain;

% augment the original dataset as needed
years = year(csv.measureDates);
data = [csv,array2table(years)];
sorted = sortrows( data, {'stationIds', 'measureDates'}, {'ascend', 'ascend'} );

% example looping through your data
for i = 1 : size( sorted, 1 )
    fprintf( 'Id=%d, year=%d, temp=%g, rain=%g', sorted.stationIds( i ), sorted.years( i ), sorted.temp( i ), sorted.rain( i ) );
    if( i > 1 && sorted.stationIds( i )==sorted.stationIds( i-1 ) && sorted.years( i )==sorted.years( i-1 ) )
        fprintf( ' => absolute difference with day before: %g', abs( sorted.temp( i ) - sorted.temp( i-1 ) ) );
    end
    fprintf( '\n' ); % new line
end

% depending on the statistics you wish to do, other more efficient ways of
% accessing summary stats might be accessible, for example:
grpstats( data ...
    , {'stationIds','years'} ... % group by categories
    , {'mean','min','max','meanci'} ... % statistics we want
    , 'dataVars', {'temp','rain'} ... % variables on which to calculate stats
) % doesn't require data to be sorted or any looping
```

This produces one line printed for each row of data (and only calculates difference in temperature when there is no year or station change). It also produces some summary stats at the end, here's what I get:

```
              stationIds    years    GroupCount    mean_temp    min_temp    max_temp      meanci_temp       mean_rain    min_rain    max_rain      meanci_rain   
              __________    _____    __________    _________    ________    ________    ________________    _________    ________    ________    ________________

    1_2016    1             2016      82            63.13       30.008       99.22      58.543    67.717    6.1181       0           19.729      4.6284    7.6078
    1_2017    1             2017     365           65.914       30.028      99.813      63.783    68.045    5.0075       0           19.933      4.3441    5.6708
    1_2018    1             2018     365           65.322       30.218      99.773      63.275    67.369    4.7039       0           19.884      4.0615    5.3462
    1_2019    1             2019     188           63.642        31.16      99.654      60.835    66.449    5.9186       0           19.864      4.9834    6.8538
    2_2016    2             2016      82           65.821       31.078      98.144      61.179    70.463    4.7633       0           19.688      3.4369    6.0898
    2_2017    2             2017     365           66.002       30.054      99.896      63.902    68.102    4.5902       0           19.902      3.9267    5.2537
    2_2018    2             2018     365           66.524       30.072      99.852      64.359     68.69    4.9649       0           19.812      4.2967    5.6331
    2_2019    2             2019     188           66.481       30.249      99.889      63.647    69.315    5.2711       0           19.811      4.3234    6.2189
    3_2016    3             2016      82           61.996       32.067      98.802      57.831    66.161    4.5445       0           19.898      3.1523    5.9366
    3_2017    3             2017     365           63.914       30.176      99.902      61.932    65.896    4.8879       0           19.934       4.246    5.5298
    3_2018    3             2018     365           63.653       30.137      99.991      61.595    65.712    5.3728       0           19.909      4.6943    6.0514
    3_2019    3             2019     188           64.201       30.078        99.8      61.319    67.082    5.3926       0           19.874      4.4541    6.3312
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The data is provided in this format: br/ "RS_MN006","1048","20080101","0.3","9","1" br/ "RS_MN006","1048","20080102","0","9","1" br/ "RS_MN006","1048","20080103","0","9","1" br/ The second column contains the stations ids, third column are measurement dates and fourth are the measurement values. I wasn't accurate in my opening post. This dataset only contains rainfall, but the dataset with temperature values is equal to this. br/ So I have some trouble understanding your loop.

Comment: In case of the rainfall dataset I want to be able to do an anual plot of the data and to sum up monthly rainfall. As for the temperature data I also want to do some plots. Anual course and anual day to day differences. Furthermore mean, min and max temperature as given in your table except that it would be helpful on a monthly basis.

Comment: What you are describing seems coherent with my example so it should be straightforward from here. the only thing missing perhaps is the transformation of your date into a matlab date, which you can do by using https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html

Comment: If I'm using readtable to read the data Matlab reads every column as string. So I can't use grpstats. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: If the problem was reading the csv, it would really have helped, and saved everyone time, for you to include a csv to start with. It s not too late to do so (a subset, with modified data if confidential, can be shared online). As your question stands it seemed more about looping through records than about importing data... But if the question is now about how to import, I would simply use the import facility included in the Matlab GUI: it will generate the apropriate code for you as a bonus. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

If you still need assistance, I would consider importing the .csv file data using "readtable". So long as only the first row are text, MATLAB will create a 'table' variable (this shouldn't be an issue for a .csv file). The individual columns can be accessed via "tablename.header" and can be reestablished as double data type (ex variable_1=tablename.header). You can then concatenate your dataset as you like. As for sorting by date and station id, I would advocate using "sortrows". For example, if the station id is the first column, sortrow(data,1) will sort "data" by the station id. sortrow(data, [1 2]) will sort "data" by the first column, then by the second column. From there, you can write an if statement to compare the station id's and perform the required calculations. I hope my brief answer is somewhat helpful.
A basic code structure would be:

```
path=['copy and paste file path here']; % show matlab where to look
data=readtable([path '\filename.csv'], 'ReadVariableNames',1); % read the file from csv format to table 
variable1=data.header1 % general example of making double type variable from table
variable2=data.header2
variable3=data.header3
double_data=[variable1 variable2 variable3]; % concatenates the three columns together 
sorted_data=sortrows(double_data, [1 2]); % sorts double_data by column 1 then column 2
```

Comment: I've some problems using the readtable function. If I read the csv file using readtable Matlab reads all columns as string. Do you have any idea how to assess that problem?

Comment: The function "str2num" should help you with this. The function converts character arrays/strings to numeric arrays. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html

Comment: Also, you can check the format of the .csv file. Right-click on the cells in a given column and select "Format Cells". Selecting "number" where applicable may help. If not, "str2num" should do the trick.